# Cocos2d if statement logic not working

Tags: iphone, if-statement, cocos2d-iphone, logic

The if statement is:
   `//these x & y do not affect the if statement they are used for the result 6 lines down.
    int x = enemy.position.x;
    int y = enemy.position.y;
    NSLog(@"%G,%G", leftJoystick.velocity.x, leftJoystick.velocity.y);`

```
if ((leftJoystick.stickPosition.x < 1 && leftJoystick.stickPosition.x > -1)&& leftJoystick.stickPosition.y > 0) {
    enemy.position = ccp(x,y-1);
    NSLog(@"North");
    return;
}
```

In the feedback it shows that `-0.0544645,0.998516` works and it logs North,                but `-0.0725357,0.997366` doesn't work. I don't understand why?

I'm trying to do this in cocos2d BTW.

Comment: why do you expect "`int`" values (for x & y) to keep floating point precision when you call into the "`ccp`" function, or maybe I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Different question. If you want to go north, which is a vertical (Y axis) direction, why do you even care about the position of the joystick in the horizontal direction (X axis)? Looks superfluous to check the X axis to be within -1 to 1 range, what purpose does that serve?

Comment: To differentiate between north, northeast, and northwest...

Comment: @Michael Dautermann the int x & y are only used for the positioning of the player the problem is with leftJoystick.stickPosition.x & y

Comment: you are logging velocity, yet your logic operates on position. Clear that up, maybe the answer will come to you more clearly.

Comment: the logic operates on the x and y value of the velocity...

Comment: that is not what i am reading : leftJoystick.stickPosition.x < 1 && leftJoystick.stickPosition.x

Comment: WOW I feel like such an idiot. Thanks for that, I guess when your stuck on the same problem for a while you start to ignore the obvious.

Comment: limite the damages ... accept an answer :)

Comment: kinda new to stack overflow how do I accept your answer?

Comment: lol, because it is not an answer. You have the option (i think) to accept your own question. But i'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are logging velocity, yet your logic operates on position. Clear that up, maybe the answer will come to you more clearly.